# How to use date_format in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to get the date and time serparted from a datetime datatype column. 
Here is my following code:

```
sqlgetInfo = "SELECT Name, DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, '%d %b %Y') AS date, DATE_FORMAT(recordTime, '%T') AS time FROM logTracker WHERE actionType = 'update' AND reportType = 'BM'"

Dim infoAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlgetInfo, Conn)
Dim infoTable As DataTable
Dim infoDataSet As New DataSet()
infoAdapter.Fill(infoDataSet, "info")
infoTable = infoDataSet.Tables("info")
For Each infoRow As DataRow In infoTable.Rows
    Response.Write("<td>" & infoRow("Name") & "/" & infoRow("date") & "/" & infoRow("time") & "</td>")
Next
Response.Write("</tr>")
```

Somehow when I run it having errors like 'DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: What database you queried(SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle or ...)?

Comment: SQL Server in visual studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use buil-in function `CONVERT` in your sql-query:

```
SELECT Name
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recordTime, 104) AS date
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), recordTime, 108) AS time 
FROM logTracker WHERE actionType = 'update' AND reportType = 'BM'"
```

Where parameters `104` and `108` is a [style of date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
Choose style format which cover your needs better...